# Can I determine the GROUP BY clause based on a parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a stored procedure and I'm trying to reduce the size of the IF blocks and wondered if it was possible to determine the GROUP BY clause based on a parameter. I'll show you what I mean:

This is not SQL code, but written as to what I'm trying to achive...

```
SELECT...

GROUP BY
IF @groupBy = 0
    DATEPART(yy, MyDBDateField)
ELSEIF @groupBy = 1
    DATEPART(yy, MyDBDateField),
    DATEPART(m, MyDBDateField)
ELSE
    DATEPART(yy, MyDBDateField),
    DATEPART(m, MyDBDateField),
    DATEPART(d, MyDBDateField)
```

So, I'm trying to group my data either by Year, Month or Day depending on a parameter. Sounds simple, but it looks like I have to copy-paste the statement into IF blocks.

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can CASE it: but you also need the same expression in the SELECT too

```
SELECT
   ...,
   DATEPART(yy, MyDBDateField),
   CASE WHEN @groupBy = 1 THEN DATEPART(m, MyDBDateField) ELSE NULL END,
   CASE WHEN @groupBy = 2 THEN DATEPART(d, MyDBDateField) ELSE NULL END
FROM



GROUP BY
   DATEPART(yy, MyDBDateField),
   CASE WHEN @groupBy = 1 THEN DATEPART(m, MyDBDateField) ELSE NULL END,
   CASE WHEN @groupBy = 2 THEN DATEPART(d, MyDBDateField) ELSE NULL  END
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can do this with dynamic sql.

Basically you pass in the group by as params then do something like

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Query = 'SELECT something FROM whatever WHERE a = b GROUP BY '+@GroupByParam
```

Then use `sp_executeSql` to run your querystring.

Some people prefer this approach, others find it can be a bit messy, it all depends on your personal preference and what you need to do.